# Help to resolve an integral

Tags: integration

I am reading an article (effect of carbon taxes and subsidies on optimal forest rotation age and supply of carbon services) that has the following integral:

$$ PV(c)= \int_0^T pcαQ'(t)e^{-rt}\, dt$$

Later on, the article states that "integrating by parts gives":

$$ PV(c)= pcα \left(Q(T)e^{-rT} + r∫_0^T Q(t)e^{-rt} dt\right) $$

I have been trying to resolve this integral but cannot arrive at the primitive function, that is, at the second equation. I admit my math is rusty. Any help will be most welcome. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

$$\int_{0}^T f^{\prime}(t)g(t)dt = f(t)g(t)  \Bigg| ^{T}_{0}  -\int_0^T f(t)g^{\prime}(t)dt$$

with $f(t)=Q(t)$ and $g(t)=e^{-rt}$. So $g^{\prime}(t)=-re^{rt}$.